# Highcharts polar with no y-axis plot lines

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to remove/hide the concentric circles (yAxis plotLines) that Highcharts automatically draws in polar charts? Setting the yAxis lineWidth to zero did not work. Also, setting the yAxis plotLines to an empty array did not work.

These options successfully create a green plot band filling the chart, but do not create a red plot line in the chart. However, what appears to be a light grey y-axis plot line circle is drawn at y=5. This is the line I want to remove or hide.

```
{
  colors: COMPETITOR_COLORS,
  chart: {
    polar: true,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    plotBackgroundColor: KAHN_DARK_GRAY_BG,
  },
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueDecimals: 2,
    headerFormat: '<br/>',
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    borderWidth: 0,
  },
  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360,
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    tickInterval: 45,
    labels: {
      format: '{}',
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    plotLines: [{color: 'red', value: 7, width: 3}],
    plotBands: [{color: 'green', from: 0, to: 10}],
    labels: {
      format: '{}',
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 45,
      pointInterval: 90,
    },
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
    },
  },
  series: kahnSeries,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines that you want to remove are grid lines, not plot lines. To remove them use:

```
yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    ...
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/46xvajn5/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineWidth

Comment: But here changing the series values of y the plot band background is not coming so how to get make plot band consistence at every value ?

Comment: Hi @Sahithi Mangena, Please create a new SO question with more a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: @ ppotaczek [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78138841/how-to-calculate-the-plot-band-tomax-value-for-a-polar-triangle-shape-highch[link] please find the link for the question. Can u please help on this .